# Calculating the median difference between elements with a (particular pair) of consecutive integer indices residing in the same sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

NOTE: I formally made a serious mistake in the first example provided.  `pointLists[[1]]` had an extra element, and we should have a guarantee that `Length[pointLists[[i]]] == Length[indexLists[[i]]]`.  I apologize for wasting people's time with this.

---

I have a list `pointLists` of sublists of 2D coordinates, where an `N = 3` example looks like this:

```
pointLists = 
 {{
   {131.048, 243.364}, {131.046, 243.321}, {131.037, 243.357}, 
   {130.931, 243.391}, {130.909, 243.377}}, {{164.911, 244.039}, {164.929, 243.942}, 
   {164.74, 244.083}}, {{98.1685, 239.618}, {98.1913, 239.6}, {98.1528, 239.623}
 }};
```

I also have another list `indexLists` (where `indexLists[[i]]` corresponds to `pointLists[[i]]`) which assigns an integer value $\geq 1$ to each coordinate in each sublist.  An example of `indexLists` for the above example looks like this:

```
indexLists = {{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

What I'd like to calculate here, as quickly as possible, is a list `differenceList` where a position `k` in `differenceList` corresponds to the mean or median difference between coordinates in the same sublist of `pointLists` where the first coordinate and the second coordinate have values of `k` and `(k-1)` in `indexLists`.  Sometimes, however, there will be no examples in any of `pointLists` satisfying this criterion.  In this case I'd like to simply set `differenceList[[k]] = "NULL"` (or really anything distinct and addressable).

---

Here's another way of thinking about the question:

Imagine, for example, that we have a bunch of cells growing in different colonies/plates, and their color changes over time.  But we can't always measure the change for each colony at every time point, just whenever we can.

Each time we measure a color, we add it on the end of a sublist corresponding to the colony in `pointLists` and we time stamp the addition by adding the time to a position at the same index as `pointLists` in `indexLists`.  We then ask... for some time point (e.g. $T = 5$), what's the median change from the previous timepoint (e.g. $T = 4$)?

And now imagine that I unfortunately have no control over this data formatting.  I just have a structure like `pointLists` and `indexLists` to work with from measurement device.

---

Descriptive Example -

Since the description provided is a little wordy, let's plug through the above example in a step-wise fashion (this is optimized for easy reading, and should in no way constrain any algorithm that can achieve the same result):

(k = 1) We set `differenceList[[1]] = {0,0}` to handle this special case.

(k = 2) For `k=2` we notice that `pointLists[[1]]`, `pointLists[[2]]`, and `pointLists[[3]]` have coordinates with `indexLists` values of $k = 2$ and $1$.  We compute the differences as, for the first sublist: `{131.046, 243.321} - {131.048, 243.364} = {-0.002, -0.043}`, for the second sublist: `{164.929, 243.942} - {164.911, 244.039} = {0.018, -0.097}`, and for the third sublist: `{98.1913, 239.6} - {98.1685, 239.618} = {0.0228, -0.018}`.  We then set: `differenceList[[2]] = Median[{{-0.002, -0.043}, {0.018, -0.097}, {0.0228, -0.018}}] = {0.018, -0.043}`.

(k = 3) For `k=3` we notice that `pointLists[[1]]` and `pointLists[[3]]` have coordinates with `indexLists` values of $k = 3$ and $2$ (and that `pointLists[[2]]` does NOT have any coordinates satisfying this criterion).  We compute the differences as - for the first sublist: `{131.037, 243.357} - {131.046, 243.321} = {-0.009, 0.036}`, and for the third sublist: `{98.1528, 239.623} - {98.1913, 239.6} = {-0.0385, 0.023}`.  We then set: `differenceList[[3]] = Median[{{-0.009, 0.036}, {-0.0385, 0.023}}] = {-0.02375, 0.0295}`.

(k = 4) For `k=4` we notice that none of the sublists have coordinates with an associated index value of $4$ AND ALSO a coordinate with an associated index value of $3$ in `indexLists`, so we set `differenceList[[4]] = "NULL"`.

(k = 5) For `k=5` we notice that, while `pointLists[[1]]` has a coordinate with an index value in `indexLists` of $5$, and `pointLists[[2]]` has a coordinate with an index value in `indexLists` of $4$, two coordinates with indices $4$ and $5$ not present in the same sublist, and there are no other examples where a sublist has both values, so we set `differenceList[[5]] = "NULL"`.

(k = 6) For `k=6` we notice that `pointLists[[1]]` has coordinates with indices $k = 6$ and $k = 5$ in `pointLists`, and that this is a lone example, so we set `differenceList[[6]] = {130.909, 243.377} - {130.931, 243.391} = {-0.022, -0.014}`.

Done.  And our result is:

```
differenceList = 
  {{0,0}, {0.018, -0.043}, {-0.02375, 0.0295}, "NULL", "NULL", {-0.022, -0.014}}
```

---

Is there a clever way to achieve the same result as above for very large instances of `pointLists` (in terms of both the number and length of component sublists)?  If it matters, I'd like to optimize for speed and not necessarily memory usage.

Also, since I'd like to be able to rerun the algorithm after updating `pointLists`, is there some way to quickly calculate the `differenceList` value at specific positions (i.e. for specific values of $k$) without recalculating the entire list?

---

---

---

Let's do one more quick example where we calculate `differenceList[[5]]` for new versions of `pointLists` and `indexLists`.

```
pointLists = {{{122.534, 191.041}, {122.735, 191.023}, {122.692, 190.999}, {122.742, 191.051}}, {{16.2591, 182.679}, {16.2429, 182.681}, {16.3327, 182.726}, {16.4354, 182.733}, {16.4144, 182.737}, {16.3727, 182.759}, {16.3141, 182.783}, {16.3692, 182.77}, {16.4068, 182.745}, {16.3346, 182.712}}};

indexLists = {{1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
```

Here's a description of how to to calculate `differenceList[[5]]` in the new example:

From `pointLists[[1]]` we calculate: `{122.742, 191.051} - {122.692, 190.999} = {0.05, 0.052}`.  From `pointLists[[2]]` we calculate: `{16.4144, 182.737} - {16.4354, 182.733} = {-0.021, 0.004}`.  And finally, we take the median of those values: `differenceList[[5]] = Median[{{0.05, 0.052},{-0.021, 0.004}}] = {0.0145, 0.028}`.

Here, `{122.742, 191.051}` & `{16.4144, 182.737}` have indices of `5` at the same position in the associated `indexLists`.  And points `{122.692, 190.999}` & `{16.4354, 182.733}` have indices of four at the same position in `indexLists`.  We calculate: `{122.742, 191.051} - {122.692, 190.999`} since these values are in the same sublist of `pointLists` (`pointLists[[1]]`), and `{16.4144, 182.737} - {16.4354, 182.733}` are both in `pointLists[[2]]`.

So that's how we do `k = 5` in the new example.

If `{122.742, 191.051}` OR `{16.4144, 182.737}` OR both are missing, we'd have `differenceList[[5]] = {-0.021, 0.004}` (and `differenceList[[5]] = {0.05, 0.052}` if `{122.692, 190.999}` OR `{16.4354, 182.733}` OR both are missing).  If three of those coordinates are missing `differenceList[[5]] = "NULL"`.

Comment: @PinguinDirk That's precisely right.  You need coordinates with both k = 4 and k = 3 values simultaneously in at least one sublist in order to not have a NULL value in the differenceList at k = 4.

Comment: @PinguinDirk Sorry, I think I'm not understanding... pointLists[[2]] has three items, the last of which has index 4?  So the point corresponding to the index k = 4 is {164.74, 244.083}.

Comment: @PinguinDirk We're only guaranteed that there will only be one point in each sublist with a particular index, that pointLists will be ordered according to the element indices in indexLists, and no guarantee that there won't be arbitrarily large gaps for the indices of consecutive points in pointLists.

Comment: @PinguinDirk I'm sorry about that :(... I've tried my best to explain with the example, but please let me know how I can improve things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10613/discussion-between-pinguin-dirk-and-hstoley)

Comment: some hours later, on chat (see link above), we identified a mistake in the original post. Will be fixed

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this isn't the fastest way, but it's a start:

```
Median /@ 
  ((SplitBy[ Sort@Flatten[{Position[indexLists, #], Position[indexLists, # - 1]}, 1], First] /. 
     {{x_Integer, y_Integer}} .. ->  Sequence[] /.
     {{a_Integer, b_Integer}, {a_Integer, d_Integer}} :> 
        (pointLists[[a, indexLists[[a, d]]]] - pointLists[[a, indexLists[[a, b]]]])) & /@ 
                                    Range@Max@Flatten@indexLists) /. Median[{}] -> Null
```

> {Null, {0.018, -0.043}, {-0.02375, 0.0295}, Null, Null, {-0.022, -0.014}}

You can set the first element to {0, 0} if you wish.

Comment: I'm getting some errors with this scheme...

Comment: Try: pointLists = {{{122.534, 191.041}, {122.735, 191.023}, {122.692, 190.999}, {122.742, 191.051}}, {{16.2591, 182.679}, {16.2429, 182.681}, {16.3327, 182.726}, {16.4354, 182.733}, {16.4144, 182.737}, {16.3727, 182.759}, {16.3141, 182.783}, {16.3692, 182.77}, {16.4068, 182.745}, {16.3346, 182.712}}};

Comment: And indexLists = {{1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};

Comment: I see a: "Part 5 of {{122.534,191.041},{122.735,191.023},{122.692,190.999},{122.742,191.051}} does not exist." error, and some other such messages.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: @PinguinDirk Odd, hold on, let me post exactly what I'm running.

Comment: @PinguinDirk See the script I posted at the end of the question with the new example.  Both your solution and belisarius' solution give similar error messages.

Comment: @PinguinDirk We shouldn't be looking for a "Part 5" of any sublist in pointList.  There could only a single element in every sublist, leaving us with a differenceList full of NULL values.

Comment: @belisarius Apologies, my example had an error where pointLists[[1]] had an extra point (as noted in the prepend to the question).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also sure that this, too, isn't the fastest way, but I hope it'll help me/us understand the problem a bit better: (adjusted to the **edited** version)

```
doStuff[points_, indices_] :=
  Module[{pos},
    pos = Pick[#1, #2, 1] & @@@ Transpose@{Rest /@ indices, Differences /@ indices};
    (Median /@ 
       Apply[#1 - #2 &, 
         Map[Extract[points, #] &, 
          (Position[pos, #] /. {x_Integer, y_Integer} :> 
           {{x, Position[indices[[x]], #][[1, 1]]}, 
            {x, Position[indices[[x]], #][[1, 1]] - 1}} & /@ 
           Range[2, Max@pos]), {2}], {2}] /. Median[{}] -> "NULL") ~Prepend~ {0, 0}]
```

So:

```
doStuff[pointLists, indexLists]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0.018, -0.043}, {-0.02375, 0.0295}, "NULL", "NULL", {-0.022, -0.014}}

How do I do it? In `pos`, I get the positions of relevant numbers (i.e. where we have an index that is only 1 bigger than the previous). Using that, I extract the relevant values of the `pointsLists`, subtract, median.

**Note on edit**:
please be aware that I wrote the code on the first version and then adapted to the edit. Thus, it is definitely suboptimal. But before adjusting, I want to make sure I get the output right.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert zeros in for the missing data so that it makes a rectangular packed array.  The some of the operations can be made efficient.  If most of the data is not missing, this might not be very wasteful.  The trade-off is the use of packed arrays.

In my solution, I'm not sure I'm constructing the padded arrays in the most efficient way.  Almost half the time is spent setting these up in the first timing example below.  Around 40% is taken up by `Median`.  The rest of it is pretty efficient by comparison.

```
medDiff[pointLists_, indexLists_] := 
 Module[{paddedPts, paddedIdx, picklist},
  paddedPts = ConstantArray[0., {Length @ pointLists, Max[indexLists], 2}];
  paddedIdx = ConstantArray[0, {Length @ indexLists, Max[indexLists]}];
  Do[
   paddedPts[[i, indexLists[[i]]]] = pointLists[[i]];
   paddedIdx[[i, indexLists[[i]]]] = ConstantArray[1, Length@indexLists[[i]]],
   {i, Length@indexLists}];

  picklist = Most@# Rest@# &@ Transpose @ paddedIdx;
  Median /@ Pick[Transpose @ Differences[paddedPts, {0, 1}], picklist, 1]
  ]
```

Example:

```
medDiff[pointLists, indexLists]
(* {{0.018, -0.043}, {-0.02375, 0.0295}, Median[{}], Median[{}], {-0.022, -0.014}} *)
```

One can use `Median[{}]` to mark the null results or apply a replacement rule such as `% /. _Median -> Null`.  One can also `Prepend` `{0, 0}` if desired.

*Timing*

```
SeedRandom[1];
coloniesN = 100;
dataN = 10^4;
len = RandomInteger[{coloniesN - 10, coloniesN}, dataN]; (* up to 10 missed meas. *)
points = Table[RandomReal[{100, 110}, {len[[i]], 2}], {i, dataN}];
indices = Table[Sort@RandomSample[Range@coloniesN, len[[i]]], {i, dataN}];

medDiff[points, indices] /. _Median -> Null // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.339532 *)
```

We calculate **all** the differences and `Pick` out the valid ones.  How much time is wasted depends on the density of the valid measurements. The array `paddedIdx` really works like a binary mask indicating which elements in `paddedPts` are valid.  Offsetting this by one place, I compute a mask of which differences are valid my multiplying `Most` and `Rest` of each row to store in `picklist`, which passed to `Pick`.

It is about 80 times faster than Pinguin Dirk's solution:

```
doStuff[points, indices] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 29.595675 *)
```

If we increase the number of missed measurements, `medDiff` is only 45 times faster:

```
SeedRandom[1];
coloniesN = 100;
dataN = 10^4;
len = RandomInteger[{coloniesN / 10, coloniesN}, dataN]; (* up to 90 missed meas. *)
points = Table[RandomReal[{100, 110}, {len[[i]], 2}], {i, dataN}];
indices = Table[Sort@RandomSample[Range@coloniesN, len[[i]]], {i, dataN}];

medDiff[points, indices] /. _Median -> Null // AbsoluteTiming // First
doStuff[points, indices] // AbsoluteTiming // First

(*  0.229826
   10.418164 *)
```

Comment: Very nice answer - I shall rethink my answer again, when I find time. I wrote my idea based on a slightly different question, thus it is by no means efficient. But I'd love to try n see if I can get at least a bit closer to your solution, with regard to timings.

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thanks.  There's certainly some waste in my solution, so theoretically a faster one might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[pointLists_, indexLists_, k_ /; k > 1] :=
 Module[{thr, col, cln},
  thr = Thread[{pointLists, indexLists}];
  col = If[
      And[MemberQ[#[[2]], k], 
       MemberQ[#[[2]], 
        k - 1]], #[[1, First@Position[#[[2]], k]]] - #[[1, 
         First@Position[#[[2]], k - 1]]], {}] & /@ thr;
  cln = col /. {} -> Sequence[] ;
  If[cln == {}, "Null", Median[cln]]
  ]
f[pointLists_, indexLists_, 1] := {0, 0}
```

Using:

```
pointLists = {{{131.048, 243.364}, {131.046, 243.321}, {131.037, 
     243.357}, {130.931, 243.391}, {130.909, 243.377}}, {{164.911, 
     244.039}, {164.929, 243.942}, {164.74, 244.083}}, {{98.1685, 
     239.618}, {98.1913, 239.6}, {98.1528, 239.623}}};
indexLists = {{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

then

```
Table[f[pointLists, indexLists, j], {j, 6}]
```

yields:

```
{{-0.02375, 0.0295}}, "Null", "Null", {{-0.022, -0.014}}}
```